# NetLogo: How to implement `sentence-map` (aka `flatMap`)?

Tags: functional-programming, netlogo

NetLogo has a `map` primitive that runs a reporter task on each element of an input list and collects a list of the results.

Many programming languages that have `map` also have something called `flatMap` (or monadic `bind` or `collect` or `SelectMany` or `mapcan` or `append-map`) that does the same thing, but allows (or requires) the reporter task to report a list of results instead. The end result is a single list containing all of the result lists concatenated.

In Logo (including in NetLogo), the concatenation part is called `sentence`, so a good name for the operation combining mapping with concatenation might be `sentence-map`.

So for example, we want:

```
observer> show sentence-map task [list ? ?] [1 2 3]
observer: [1 1 2 2 3 3]
```

Note that `sentence` doesn't require all of its inputs to be lists. For example, `(sentence 1 [2 3] 4)` evaluates to `[1 2 3 4]`. So our definition of `sentence-map` will follow suit. Example:

```
observer> show sentence-map task [ifelse-value (? mod 2 = 0) [(list ? ?)] [?]] [1 2 3]
observer: [1 2 2 3]
```

How can `sentence-map` be implemented, and is the implementation efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to define `sentence-map` is as follows:

```
to-report sentence-map [f xs]
  report reduce sentence map f xs
end
```

As for efficiency, if you are using NetLogo 5.0.5 or newer, this definition should perform well (O(n)-ish runtime).

In NetLogo 5.0.4 and earlier versions, the repeated use of `sentence` will make the overall time O(n<sup>2</sup>) due to [this NetLogo bug](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/407) (where the underlying cause was [this Scala bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7725)).

If for some reason you're stuck using an older version of NetLogo, you could work around it by writing your own version of `sentence` that does concatenation by repeatedly calling `lput`, and then using that inside `sentence-map`.

Comment: `reduce` can be applied to `turtle-set`, `patch-set`, and `link-set` to a similar end. For example, to get the link neighbors of my link neighbors in a turtleset, you can do `reduce turtle-set [ link-neighbors ] of link-neighbors`.